# How to call controller [HttpPost] method using angular js $http post?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I have a controller method as below.

```
public class ProcessorController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public void Paid(string confirmationNumber)
   {

   }
}
```

I am trying to call this method from a function in angular js as below. The $http.post is not working. I see an error 'The resource cannot be found' in fiddler when it is trying to hit the path that is specified in $http.post. Can anyone please point out what is going wrong here? Thank you!

```
var payControllers = angular.module('payControllers', []);
payControllers.controller('payCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
       function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.Process = function(confnumber) {
        $scope.ConfNumber = confnumber;

            if ($scope.ConfNumber.length > 0) {
                    $http.post('/Processor/Paid',
                       {
                           confirmationNumber: $scope.ConfNumber
                       }
                     ).success(function () {
                         alert('updated')
                     });
              }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't the url be '/api/processor/paid' ?

Comment: Thank you. The issue was with url.

Comment: If only you had asked public void Paid(MyLittleObject obj) where MyLittleObject had a few scalars on it.  I'm dying on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
var payControllers = angular.module('payControllers', []);
payControllers.controller('payCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
       function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.Process = function(confnumber) {
        $scope.ConfNumber = confnumber;

            if ($scope.ConfNumber.length > 0) {
                    $http({
                           url: '/api/Processor/Paid?confirmationNumber='+$scope.ConfNumber,
                           method: 'POST'
                    }).success(function (data) {
                        alert('updated');
                    });
              }
    }
}]);
```